# Unable to install Visual Studio 2015 on Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2008

When downloading Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web and running the vsn_full_ENU.exe, I get the following message: **The specified program requires a newer version of windows.**

The [Visual Studio 2015 compability table](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx) clearly state that Visual Studio 2015 is compatible with Windows Server 2008. Why do I get this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [table you linked to](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs.aspx) shows which operating systems will run the applications that VS2015 can build, not which operating systems VS2015 will itself run on.

As you can see in the [system requirements table for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#6), Windows Server 2008 is not supported.  You must have at least Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Is it still possible to download Visual Studio 2010? Can not find any links on the download page at Visual Studio's home page

Comment: Microsoft's web site seems to have failed, so I can't check.  But once it's back up, I suggest you try a search on the download center.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time being redirected on the phone between Microsoft Developer Network and Microsoft Technical support I finally got my answer:

I need a MSDN Subscription associated with my Microsoft account to be able to download Visual Studio 2010 Express from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/securedownloads). The free to download version of Visual Studio only apply to the latest version of Visual Studio (atm Visual Studio 2015 Express).